# Error with Flutter ProviderScope and Web Build

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and came across this issue:

```
$ flutter build web

 Building with sound null safety 

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
lib/main.dart:5:11:
Error: Couldn't find constructor 'ProviderScope'.
    const ProviderScope(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

The code I have is the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I solve this compilation issue?

The reference to the tutorial I am following is: https://thiagoevoa.medium.com/creating-an-end-to-end-project-from-node-js-backend-to-flutter-app-a8df8ffdde5b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An import is missing:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It works! thank you for pointing out the obvious!